# list of emacs commands executed

Tags: emacs, command, elisp

I am using emacs and the auto-newline feature is not working as expected. I have a pretty large number of customizations done to my emacs. So it would be no wonder if one of the other customizations is not what auto-line is expecting. I would like to know if there is a way to know the list of commands (list of emacs commands) executed by emacs at a particular point, for e.g. when ctrl-s ctrl-c or in my case when auto-line feature is called.

edit : I think you have misunderstood the question. I would like to know what command emacs calls 'internally'.

Comment: at least for one of those cases you can use "describe-key"

Answer (score 1):

I believe `view-lossage` is what you're looking for -- `M-x view-lossage`, or `C-h l`.

If you want to know what a keystroke is bound to, consider using `describe-key`, which is usually bound to `C-h k`.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. I would like to know what command emacs calls 'internally'.

Comment: Oh, you want to see the all the calls that get made in the course of executing a command? I don't know an easy way to do that; I'd start by just reading the source for the function you're interested in. (If you hit `C-h f` and type in the function name, the filename where the function came from is a link -- hit enter or mouse-click to visit the function definition.

Comment: On the top of help(opened with C-h k) you can click on the source button.

Answer (score 1):

Basically at this point, you need to bite the bullet and learn some Emacs-lisp.  The debugger is what you are looking for to dig further into your problem (I use `edebug`).  It's not just about seeing what functions get called, you also need to see the values of the relevant variables when those functions are called.

If you feel you're not up to it, then you can bi-sect your init file until you find the culprit, but at that point you still need some Emacs-lisp to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @event_jr said --

What you seem to be asking is the history of the *functions called* by the command you last invoked. (You speak of Emacs *"internal commands"*, but it seems you just mean functions.)

To get that history for any given command you invoke (e.g., by a key), use `M-x debug-on-entry` and then enter the command name.  The next time you use that command, you can walk through its execution in the Emacs debugger (hit `d` to step, `c` to continue past a step).